# XSLT and nested elements

Tags: html, xslt, xhtml

Given the XSL template and XML below, here's the HTML output i'm trying to achieve (more or less):

```
<p>
foo goes here
  <span class="content"><p>blah blah blah</p><p>blah blah blah</p></span>
bar goes here
  <span class="content">blah blah blah blah blah blah</span> 
</p>
```

Here is what is actually getting rendered (entire contents of <span.content> missing):

```
<p>
foo goes here
  <span class="content"></span>
bar goes here
  <span class="content">blah blah blah blah blah blah</span> 
</p>
```

Here's my template (snippet):

```
 <xsl:template match="note[@type='editorial']">
   <span class="content">
     <xsl:apply-templates />
   </span>
 </xsl>
 <xsl:template match="p">
   <p>
     <xsl:apply-templates />
   </p>
 </xsl>
```

Here's my xml:

```
<p>
foo goes here
  <note type="editorial"><p>blah blah blah</p><p>blah blah blah</p></note>
bar goes here
  <note type="editorial">blah blah blah blah blah blah</note> 
</p>
```

**Rendering particular elements is not important.** ie. I don't care whether a <p> or <div> or <span> gets rendered, so long as none of the text elements are lost.
I would like to avoid creating a specific rule to match "p/note/p", assuming that a <note> element can contain any arbitrary children.

I'm a total noob to xsl, so any additional tips or pointers would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't show the `<note ...>` tags in your input XML that your XSL is trying to match.  Please edit your post and provide the `<note>` wrapper tags in their correct position in the input.

Comment: There are two <note> elements in the xml input, the final block quote. The two blocks at the top are the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I'm just fussing around and here's the solution i finally came up with.

Nested <p> tags just don't work. Your browser doesn't like them, and XSLT doesn't like them either. So, I switched everything to <divs> and <spans>

Also, I added a couple catch-all templates to the end of my template.

Here's the final version that's working well enough for my purposes:

```
<xsl:template match="note[@type='editorial']">
   <span class="content">
     <xsl:apply-templates />
   </span>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="p">
  <div class="para">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
  <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:template>
```

h/t:

http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/defaultrule.html

and [How can xsl:apply-templates match only templates I have defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346362/how-can-xslapply-templates-match-only-templates-i-have-defined#346444)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `apply-templates` instead of `apply-template`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="note[@type='editorial']">
        <span class="content">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </span>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="p">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, i fixed that typo in the original and still didn't fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="p"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="p">
    <p>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </p>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="span">
     <note type="editorial">
     <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="child::*">
     <xsl:copy-of select="child::*"/>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    </note>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: this doesn't achieve the desired output